# pandoc not available when knitting .rmd in vscode

Tags: r, macos

So I'm new to R, and I've been trying to knit my .rmd files in VSCode. I've installed the pandoc and rmarkdown and knitr packages. The knitting works fine in RStudio but I prefer VSCode as a text editor, I can't seem to find any MacOS specific fixes for this either. Anyone got any ideas?

Here is the error:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_available
> function (version = NULL, error = FALSE)
> {
> find_pandoc()
> found \<- !is.null(.pandoc$dir) && (is.null(version) || .pandoc$version \>=
> version)
> msg \<- c("pandoc", if (!is.null(version)) c("version", version,
> "or higher"), "is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).")
> if (error && !found)
> stop2(paste(msg, collapse = " "))
> found
> }
> \<bytecode: 0x14ba920a8\>
> \<environment: namespace:rmarkdown\>
```

Here are the packages installed (most of which I've omitted)

```
               License_restricts_use OS_type MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built  

knitr          NA                    NA      NA     "no"             "4.2.0"

pandoc         NA                    NA      NA     "no"             "4.2.0"

rmarkdown      NA                    NA      NA     "no"             "4.2.0"
roxygen2       NA                    NA      NA     "yes"            "4.2.0"
```

And here is my session:

```
> utils::sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pandoc_0.1.0   knitr_1.42     rmarkdown_2.20

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.4     utf8_1.2.3      digest_0.6.31   rappdirs_0.3.3 
 [5] lifecycle_1.0.3 jsonlite_1.8.4  magrittr_2.0.3  evaluate_0.20  
 [9] pillar_1.8.1    rlang_1.0.6     cli_3.6.0       fs_1.6.1       
[13] vctrs_0.5.2     tools_4.2.2     glue_1.6.2      xfun_0.37      
[17] fastmap_1.1.1   compiler_4.2.2  pkgconfig_2.0.3 htmltools_0.5.4
[21] tibble_3.1.8
```

Comment: You should run `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()` with the parenthesis to actually run the function rather than just see it's code. Note that pandoc is a system dependency and not an R package itself.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had assumed it was a package. That makes so much more sense.